# Minecraft console get wrong commands

Tags: console, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I started a local server and want to add some simple commands with python, the server is running with forge 1.12 and a couple of mods.
My idea was it to catch wrong commands and send the right result instead.
An easy test command would be  `/echo Hello World` with the result in the chat `Hello World`.
To get the command I am using the last line of the latest console log file, which is equal to the current console content. But in the console I cant read wrong commands. So if I run the echo command I get an message in the chat `Unknown command. Try /help for a list of commands`.
I think there could be two solutions:

1. Add in any register the command to get it in the console, prevent on this way the server to response and get the command in the console to use it.
2. Find a config to print also wrong commands in the console.

Thanks for helping

Comment: I don't understand your issue. Where are you stuck exactly ? Also, can you show your code ? You're using python or minecraft-forge (which is in java) ? Please [edit] your question :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to 'cancel' commands through API, but there is a trick to effectively cancel commands anyways. You want to be listening to the Forge `CommandEvent`, modifying the command to another existing command that does nothing (you can create one yourself). This gives you a place to handle all commands (you'll have to filter for unexisting commands, otherwise you'd cancel all commands), and it will prevent the `Unknown Command` message from showing.